# How to create just one node with a new relation in java connect to a node exist in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I am getting trouble with creating nodes and relationship. I can create two nodes with a relationship by using java code below:

```
URI Node1 = add.createNode();
URI Node2=add.createNode();
URI relation1 = add.addRelationship(Node1,Node2, "wasGeneratedBy", "{}");
```

add is created previously.

But if I have node2 already in the Neo4j Graph database, and I just want to create a new node1 and a new relationship then connect to the Node2 inside the Neo4j, how to make this happen?

Comment: I assume you are doing this by the REST API by your notations. As Jatin mentioned, you will need to get the reference to `node2`, then pass it into the `addRelationship`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get reference to the other node. There are multiple ways of doing it. One way is that you know the path from the reference Node to it. Say:

```
graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase( DB_PATH );
Node node2 = graphDb.createNode();
graphDb.getReferenceNode().createRelationshipTo(
            node2, RelTypes.USERS_REFERENCE );
```

Later you can get access to `node2` from the `getReferenceNode`.

Another way would be to index it. And then use [Index](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing.html) to get reference to the Node. I would recommend looking at the [documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/) and the sample examples as they are extensive and very good.